# Can I block notifications from a separate virtual desktop?

Tags: windows-10, notifications, virtual-desktop

Windows 10 allows me to have multiple virtual desktops. Is it possible to block taskbar notifications from programs not running on the current desktop?

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:** No, it is impossible.

The reason has to do with the way notifications are generated. What you call *apps running on a certain desktop* is their window(s) associated with that desktop. But apps generate notifications without associating those notifications with a given desktop or a given window. As a matter of fact, some apps that have no windows whatsoever generate notifications. (Traditionally, however, Windows apps associated their notifications with a taskbar icon. That's not the case with Windows 8 and later.)

Comment: Has anything changed in the last four years since this question was first asked?

Comment: @JohnStoneman It is now 5 years on, and nothing has yet changed.